# parsing a file from end

Tags: php, cakephp-1.3

I have a text file that has information like this

```
##john##eva##shawn##roger##henry##david
```

I want to get the very last name at the end and ingnore rest.
How'd I do that
THanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can explode the whole string to an array and then use the php's end() function, like this:

```
// define our string
$string = "##john##eva##shawn##roger##henry##david";
// use the explode function to create an array using the delimiter ##
$array = explode("##", "##john##eva##shawn##roger##henry##david");
// print last object of the array using the php's end function
print end($array);
```

Answer (score 3):

**Big file solution:**

```
$handle = fopen("myfile.txt", "r");
$file_size = filesize("myfile.txt");

$seek_position = -1024;
fseek($handle, $seek_position, SEEK_END);
while(strpos($data = fread($handle, abs($seek_position)), '##') === false){
    $seek_position = $seek_position - 1024;
    if(abs($seek_position) > $file_size)
        break;

    fseek($handle, $seek_position, SEEK_END);
}
$val = substr(2, $data);
```

---

**Small file solution:**

```
$file_contents = get_file_contents($file_location);
$array = explode('##', $file_contents);
$val = $array[end(array_keys($array))];
unset($array);
```

Comment: This wont work if your file is more than a few megabytes in size.

Comment: Sure it will, depends on your PHP mem limit.  Also the text provided in the example was small, no mention of MB/GB of information

Comment: Who stores 4GB of information in a text file for random seeking? =D

Comment: Not if I'm developing their software and hosting their service they won't

Comment: There, I revised my answer, throw me the GBs

Comment: I would recommend larger in(de?)crements. I don't know where the optimum is for `strpos` and `fread` be but I guess it's a few hundred bytes. Certainly not 1 byte.

Answer (score 2):

Use `fseek` to quickly jump to the end of the file.

```
$handle = fopen("myfile.txt", "r");
fseek($handle, -20, SEEK_END);
$bytes = fread($handle, 20);
```

Will read the last 20 bytes of the file (and skip the rest).

Comment: You would need to guess the size of the last name.

Comment: No, you can just increase (or decrease?) the offset until you find a `#`. Reading backwards isn't any different from reading forwards. Of course my code will need to be modified to do that, but I'm not getting paid for this ;)

Comment: If your answer did that, it would be the perfect answer. Might want to edit it to fit perfectly.

Answer (score 2):

Unless you know how long the last name is going to be or at least the max length of names you can't really skip just to end of a file and pull out the name.

What you need to do is read the file into a buffer and parse it either using something like explode() and '##' and getting the last element of the returned array or using strpos() to find the last occureance of '##'and reading on from there.

Here is an example with explode.

```
$sFileName = "file.txt";

$sContents = file_get_contents($sFileName);

$aNames = explode("##", $sContents);

$sLastName = $aNames[count($aNames)-1];
```

Comment: You can jump to the end and read backwards until you find a `#`.

Answer (score 1):

After loading the file into a variable, you can find the last ocurrence of "##" using [strpos()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strrpos.php) and then read from there on using [substr()](http://ar.php.net/manual/en/function.substr.php).

Comment: This wont work if your file is more than a few megabytes in size.

Comment: He didn't specify it was a large file or anything. The answer fits the example given in the question.

Comment: He mentioned 'ingnore rest', so I assumed an `fseek` was in order. Your approach doesn't ignore the rest.